# Is there something like a root_to method in middleman?

Tags: middleman

I would like to move `source/index.html.erb` into a directory to sit nicely alongside the partials I'm using in `index.html.erb`.

**Is there an existing way to move the `source/index.html.erb` into a directory?**

Something like

```
# config.rb
root_to 'root#index'
```

So that I can do

```
source/
  root/
   |- _hero_box.html.erb
   |- index.html.erb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here. Neither involve moving `index.html.erb` out of the root of your source directory.

The first one is to provide the path to the partial in your source. It would look like:

`<%= partial 'root/hero_box' %>`

The alternative is to configure middleman to look for your partials in a specific directory:

`# config.rb
set :partials_dir, 'root'`

You would not need to prefix the partial with the path in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That's good to know. Does it seem like over-engineering to consider building an extension to have `index.html.erb` in a directory?

Comment: It really depends on your requirements... But I'm not quite sure of the reasons why you would want to move the document to a directory. After all, the end result of the build process is a static site...